# AVFoundation How to loop an audio for a specific duration?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avqueueplayer, avplayerlooper

I want to loop a specific audio for a given duration.

For example;

10 sec. audio file.
intended loop duration: 7 min.

During this loop, I have to observe the remaining time of total of the loop iterations.

I tried the `AVQueuePlayer` and `AVAudioLooper`, but there is no elegant option to track the total duration/time of the loop iterations.

I am open to new ideas.

Comment: Have you considered using ```scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:```?

Comment: Actually, I did not considered using Timer. It may be a solution. But, I am curios about if there is some built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **AVAudioPlayer**.
AVAudioPlayer have property named ***numberOfLoops*** for looping.

```
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 5
```

Comment: Using numberOfLoops does not allow you to determine the maximum duration. It may be longer than expected with numberOfLoops.

Comment: Also, I retrieve those audios through the network. AVAudioPlayer only works with local audio file.

Comment: Can't find a prebuilt option for it, but combination of AVQueuePlayer and Timer can do it.